# make failed on yarn install

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm, npm-install

Since a few days I can't install my dependencies via my package.json for CPP errors... My installation fails in the same way with npm install

```
1 error generated.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/binding/src/binding.o] Error 1
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/florian/code/project/inscriptions-v2/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/florian/code/project/inscriptions-v2/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/florian/code/project/inscriptions-v2/node_modules/vue-loading-spinner/node_modules/node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v16.16.0
```

My dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^2.0.6",
    "@lyracom/embedded-form-glue": "^1.0.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "qs": "^6.10.3",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.11",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-form-wizard": "^0.8.4",
    "vue-head": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-loading-spinner": "^1.0.11",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-progressbar": "^0.7.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.3",
    "vue-simple-spinner": "^1.2.10",
    "vue-stepper": "^1.4.2",
    "vue-toastr": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.19",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
```

I already tried to solve the problem by installing several versions of node, of name but nothing makes it I still have this error (that I do not have besides on my WSL Windows, only on my macOS machine

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the lock file, `node_modules`, and installing them again. If that doesn't help there are a few more options: https://codeforgeek.com/make-failed-with-exit-code-2/
or install the Command Line Tools for Xcode if you haven't done this yet.

Although, I still have the feeling that the Node version might cause this problem